# Issue putting a URL with special characters

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks, special-characters, url-encoding

I am having difficulty placing the following URL in my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4313675/62050), which if I copy and paste the link into my Google Chrome, it works perfectly fine.

[https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matlab_Analysis_Simplest_Lowpass.html#:~:text=ntransient%3Dlength(B)%2D1%3B%20%25%20no.%20samples%20to%20steady%20state](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matlab_Analysis_Simplest_Lowpass.html#:%7E:text=ntransient%3Dlength(B)%2D1%3B%20%25%20no.%20samples%20to%20steady%20state)

As opposed to showing the start of the page, the link above is actually a link to a highlighted text in the middle of the page as illustrated below.

[image]

I have tried the following variation but it does not work.

- https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matlab_Analysis_Simplest_Lowpass.html%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3Dntransient%253Dlength%28B%29%252D1%253B%2520%2525%2520no.%2520samples%2520to%2520steady%2520state

Comment: @bobble I am guessing that the issue is if you highlight the link and paste it in the address bar **in chrome**, it will jump to relevant text and highlight it. But if you click on it, that doesn't work. Is that right user578?

Comment: @bobble The OP since updated the link in their post with a tinyurl link which makes it work.

Comment: Here's an example that works: `https://superuser.com/questions/1305867/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-zip-file-on-windows-10-pro-64-bit#:~:text=4%20GB%20size%20is%20a,about%2016%20exabytes%20size%20limitation`  --- https://superuser.com/questions/1305867/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-zip-file-on-windows-10-pro-64-bit#:~:text=4%20GB%20size%20is%20a,about%2016%20exabytes%20size%20limitation

Comment: @Rob that's exactly what I am looking for. May I know what you are using as the link to the highlighted text?

Comment: @Rob is there an online tool that makes my URL compatible with StackExchange URL format?

Comment: I simply searched for: "~:text" and looked for a post at Stack Exchange / Overflow using Chrome browser to test and verify the link, then I copied it into a comment (and retested it).

Comment: Related usage info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162093/3648282